# How to build a GUI application with Python 3.3 and Qt 5?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

Having no Python or Qt experience I'd like to get started with the recent versions (I actually seek to make heavy use of some of the new features announced) but I couldn't find any tutorials (the most seem to use Python 2.x and Qt 4). Could you please share a link to a tutorial or just tell me what exactly do I need to started? I have reasonable experience with other languages and am not asking about learning Python itself in this issue.

Comment: Can't see why this would not be constructive. Came looking for a minimal example or link to one which would have been a nice answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro).

[Here's](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qtexamplesandtutorials.html) the Qt5 documentation. When I need help with PyQt, I will look at Qt documentation and "translate" the C++ code into Python.